# Is there a jQuery webscraper out there?

Tags: jquery, web-scraping

I'm trying to pullout some info from an external site using jQuery and Adobe AIR. Right now I'm using a hidden `div` and jQuery's load function to load fragments of the external site, once the info is loaded I parse some info with selectors. This is fine but it's kinda dirty and I need to perform this several times (don't want to need many hidden divs).

Just wondering if anybody knows a good webscraper written in jQuery or maybe another method I'm missing

Comment: Does the external site know you are going to be doing this? I guess not considering you can't use an API. -1

Comment: Why the downvote? It's perfectly ok to scrape sites that don't have an API for personal use.

Comment: I guess there's a new ethics cops team in stackoverflow.com. Now scrapping is evil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call `$.ajax`, then create a detached DOM tree by writing `$(responseHTML)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use selectors directly on the ajax response body:

```
$.get('http://somewhere.com', '',
    function (html) {
        var scrapedElement = $("#myelement", html);
    }
);
```